# ERRORs: cannot create target "rosbuild_premsgsrvgen" and roslang package cannot be found

Tags: ros, build, rosmake, package, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody.

I try to get fome openSource code I got from the Internet to work.
I use "ros groovy" and I always get the error (when triing "rosmake" or "make eclipse-project"):

**"CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:369 (add_custom_target):
add_custom_target cannot create target "rosbuild_premsgsrvgen" because
another target with the same name already exists.  The existing target is a
custom target created in source directory
"/home/pr2rpVirt/code/ratslam_ros".  See documentation for policy
CMP0002 for more details."**

[....]

**"[rosbuild] WARNING: rosbuild_genmsg() was called, but the roslang package cannot be found.  Message generation will NOT occur"**

For finding the error I set up 2 VMs with ubuntu 12.10 (x64) with ros-fuerte and ros-groovy for the other. When using fuerte I do not get this error and everything works fine. With groovy this error occurs.

The code can be found here: http:// code.google.com/p/ratslam/wiki/RatSLAMROS (please delete space after http:// first)

Here is a trace:

1.) downloading source:

```
pr2rpVirt@ubuntu:~/code$ svn checkout http:// ratslam.googlecode.com/svn/branches/ratslam_ros ratslam_ros
A    ratslam_ros/license.txt
....
A    ratslam_ros/oxford_newcollege.launch
checked out, Revision 38.
```

2.) make eclipse-project

```
pr2rpVirt@ubuntu:~/code$ cd ratslam_ros/
pr2rpVirt@ubuntu:~/code/ratslam_ros$ make eclipse-project 
mv Makefile Makefile.ros
if ! (cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" -Wno-dev . && rm Makefile && rm CMakeCache.txt && rm -rf CMakeFiles); then mv Makefile.ros Makefile && echo "**ERROR building Eclipse project!**" && false; fi
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Could not determine Eclipse version, assuming at least 3.6 (Helios). Adjust CMAKE_ECLIPSE_VERSION if this is wrong.
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.3")
-- Action Files:
[rosbuild] Building package ratslam_ros
[rosbuild] Cached build flags older than manifests; calling rospack to get flags
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/pr2rpVirt/code/ratslam_ros/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/groovy
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/groovy
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/pr2rpVirt/code/ratslam_ros/test_results
-- Looking for include files CMAKE_HAVE_PTHREAD_H
-- Looking for include files CMAKE_HAVE_PTHREAD_H - found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE 
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- catkin 0.5.70
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:369 (add_custom_target):
  add_custom_target cannot create target "rosbuild_premsgsrvgen" because
  another target with the same name already exists.  The existing target is a
  custom target created in source directory
  "/home/pr2rpVirt/code/ratslam_ros".  See documentation for policy
  CMP0002 for more details.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:18 (rosbuild_init)


-- IRRLICHT_INCLUDE_DIR = /usr/include
-- IRRLICHT_LIBRARY = /usr/lib/libIrrlicht.so
-- Found IRRLICHT: /usr/lib/libIrrlicht.so 
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so - found
-- Looking for gethostbyname
-- Looking for gethostbyname - found
-- Looking for connect
-- Looking for connect - found
-- Looking for remove
-- Looking for remove - found
-- Looking for shmat
-- Looking for shmat - found
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE - found
-- Found X11: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
-- Found OpenGL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so 
[rosbuild] WARNING: rosbuild_genmsg() was called, but the roslang package cannot be found.  Message generation will NOT occur
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:790 (add_dependencies):
  add_dependencies Adding dependency to non-existent target:
  rosbuild_precompile
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:29 (rosbuild_genmsg)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
**ERROR building Eclipse project!**
make: *** [eclipse-project] Error 1
```

3.) debug

```
pr2rpVirt@ubuntu:~/code/ratslam_ros$ rospack find roslang
/opt/ros/groovy/share/roslang
pr2rpVirt@ubuntu:~/code/ratslam_ros$ echo $ROS_ROOT
/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros
pr2rpVirt@ubuntu:~/code/ratslam_ros$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
/opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks:/home/pr2rpVirt
pr2rpVirt@ubuntu:~/code/ratslam_ros$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
pr2rpVirt@ubuntu:~/code/ratslam_ros$ echo $PATH
/opt/ros/groovy/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Does anybody has a clue what is going wrong when I use groovy insteed of fuerte?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67828/errors:-cannot-create-target-%22rosbuild_premsgsrvgen%22-and-roslang-package-cannot-be-found/) by [pr2rp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5432/pr2rp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2013-07-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

okay. The problem seems to be fixxed in the latest ros updates.
For now everything seems working now. I'll keep investigating.

---

Originally posted by [pr2rp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5432/pr2rp/) with karma: 36 on 2013-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1